# Reload a webview from URL by scrolling

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, page-refresh

I'd like to implement a way refresh my UIWebView. I thought about doing like the Facebbok or Echofon app, reload by scolling down. But I can't find anything on the subject anywhere :-( I'd like to know if it's possible, and if so, which Action should I use ?

If you have a better idea on how to reload the page, just give me your suggestions :-) *Note that my app uses a UITabBarController so I don't have much space to add a button or something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thought about using a timer to check if changes have taken into effect requiring a refresh?

Comment: Nope. I realy have to let the user decide when he want to reload the page.